# Oval Validation

Tags: validation, oval

Can we access request object in isSatisfied() (class **net.sf.oval.AbstractAnnotationCheck**) method or can we pass an extra parameter in this method to use further. I have a scenario where I need to pass locale information to isSatisfied() method and apply some conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a thread local variable for this. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage#Java